# SonarQube migrating from Oracle DB to Postgresql

Tags: sonarqube

We are running SonarQube 7.0 with Oracle DB. We would like to migrate to postgresql. We are using the community edition of SonarQube for the enterprise edition the migration is possible using the Sonar DB Copy Tool.

How is the process for the community edition ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no migration available for the Community Edition. What is available is re-creating your history by doing the following for each project:

- checkout project from begin date
- analyze using `-Dsonar.projectDate=[checkout date]`
- increment date
- `GOTO 1`

Note that this is painful and error-prone. Also, you loose your history of issues marked False Positive/Won't Fix unless you also follow up with something like the [Issue Resolver Plugin](https://github.com/willemsrb/sonar-issueresolver-plugin) to copy that.